# "Server method 'x' failed" when leaving the page during an ajax.net request

Tags: firefox, ajax.net

I'm getting an "server method 'x' failed" in FireFox when I'm in the middle of an AJAX.NET request and I leave the current page.

It seems to be generated by MicrosoftAjax.debug.js, line 5475:

result = new Sys.Net.WebServiceError(false , String.format(Sys.Res.webServiceFailedNoMsg, methodName), "", "");

But I can't figure out why it shows up, and why it does so in FireFox only.

Example: Visit http://dev.linkedpapers.com/Search.aspx?q=overflow and navigate to a different page while the search results are still loading. You should receive the error.

Answer (score 0):

Could the reason be that the Search button does a 'post' AND a asyn call back?

Comment: I don't think it does. The Search button (which is a hyperlink) only has an onclick method that changes the document.location, and no other event handlers. I've also checked the Search textbox, which does have a keypress (jQuery) event, but that does the same thing.